# Spring Boot get Query result with column is null

Tags: java, spring-boot

```
@Query("select a from UsersRelation a where a.usersId = ?1 and a.status=1 and a.activeFlag=1 and (a.requestReasonId = :requestReasonId OR a.requestReasonId is :requestReasonIdIsNull) ")
List<UsersRelation> findUsersRelationWithReason(Long usersId, @Param("requestReasonId") Long requestReasonId, @Param("requestReasonIdIsNull") Long requestReasonIdIsNull);

example call findUsersRelationWithReason(1, null)
```

but does not give me expected result such as like requestReasonId to equal something or null

Answer (score 0):

Just modify the query and ditch the second input argument

```
select a from UsersRelation a where a.usersId = ?1 and a.status=1 and a.activeFlag=1 and (a.requestReasonId = :requestReasonId OR a.requestReasonId is null)
```